# set min and max value of a qprogressBar without passing by stylesheet

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qprogressbar

I need to create a `QProgressBar` where we can choose a range, the minimum and the maximum value.

Until now, I used a stylesheet for the same but the program is working(although not perfectly).

Stylesheet will allow me each time to change my background color and also bar color and each time I should add a small value because I'm using a `qgradientline` inside of stylesheet (not a good idea because of parsing time and also the progress bar is not generic)

image that shows what i want to do exactly

[image]

You can find the stylesheet xml below :

```
 setStyleSheet(QString("QProgressBar{background-color: %2; border: 2px solid %2; border-radius: 1px; margin: 0px; text-align: center;}"
                      "Q2ProgressBar:disabled{background-color: %3; border: 2px solid %3; border-radius: 1px; margin: 0px; text-align: center;}"
                  "QProgressBar::chunk{background-color: qlineargradient(x0: 0, x2: 1, stop : 0 %1, stop: %5 %1, stop: 0.%6 %4, stop: 1 %4); margin: 0px}"
                     ).arg(Q2UiColorsLocator::get().getDispText().name(),
                           Q2UiColorsLocator::get().getDispText().name(),
                           Q2UiColorsLocator::get().getDisabled().name(),
                           Q2UiColorsLocator::get().getDispBackground().name())
                          .arg(min+0.00001)
                          .arg(((min)+0.00002)));
```

Answer (score 0):

From documentation about maximum field (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprogressbar.html#maximum-prop)

> This property holds the progress bar's maximum value
>
> When setting this property, the minimum is adjusted if necessary to
>   ensure that the range remains valid. If the current value falls
>   outside the new range, the progress bar is reset with reset().
>
> Access functions: 
>   int   maximum() const
>   void  setMaximum(int maximum)

So, have you tried with setMaximum? The same is with minimum. Access function is setMinimum

Comment: setMaximum and set minimum allow you to set the range of barGraph but what i want is to set the maximum and the minimum value mean that if i set the minimum value the bargraph will not start from 0 as i show in the picture i put . :)

Comment: So you want to set minimum value 10, and you want that the graph starts at 10?

Comment: yes this is exactly what i want, the bar can have a range of x0,x1, but when i put setminimum(10) and setmaximum(30) i want to start my graph from 10 and end it a 30.  the only solution i found now is to use qgradient with a stylesheet which is not a good idea (time of parsing adding a vilue to not have a gradiant color ..... and to much complicate if we have range of a very small or a very big numbers) so i'm trying to find another solution less complicate than that .

Comment: Hm...honestly, I have no idea how to do this. However, you can use whole qprogress bar from 0 to 100 ... and ofcouse you should use %. so if in your case range is between 10 and 30 and value is 20 that is 50%, so that qprogressbar should be at 50%. Don't know how else I can help you.

Comment: i got an idea i'll share it if it works, but i use QscrollBar, better than using a qgradientline. but should also pass by a stylesheet each time if i want to change the size of the scroller .... :(, but i think i'll won some speed and not to much complicate to write :D